# PHP mime type not working for MP3

Tags: php, header, mime-types, content-type, readfile

I am having an issue when using mime types in PHP.

As a security feature, I am placing any content uploaded to my server by users in a directory outside of public_html. When a user wants to access their uploaded files in the browser, I use php script to pull the file from the secure folder using readfile and header('content-type'), the issue I am having so far only pertains to mp3s.

When I try and use this for a mp3 file, the file doesn't actually play in the browser, but M4As work fine. And it isn't every mp3 file too, it just seems that when I get the mime-type of some mp3 files php can't tell that they are mp3s. The mp3s also playback fine if I download them, so it isn't an issue with the file per say (unless the file has the wrong mime-type somehow).

How do I get it to tell that they ARE mp3s?

My getFile code is here: [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/Yvs8TXqg)

Any help would be appreciated greatly, I'll even give you some of my tracking cookies!

Comment: Not all browsers are going to have plugins to play mp3s internally. Just setting the proper mime-type on a file doesn't make the browser magically be able to HANDLE that mime type.

Comment: But my browser DOES play mp3s internally

Answer (score 1):

For mp3s, did you try:

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
```